# Python3 BeautifulSoup find text inside variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a problem that I have to search for a text inside a variable. There are several words. 
Here's an example of what my code looks like.

```
<value uri=" /user/var/120/10251/0/0/12242" strValue="61" unit="°C" decPlaces="0" scaleFactor="10" advTextOffset="0">605</value>
```

It is the tag `value` that I can display without any problems. 
Now I only need the value contained in the variable "strValue".
Unfortunately, I can't find any help in the documentary.

I hope you can help me with that!

Comment: What code are you using to parse that HTML that you aren't able to make access the `strValue` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use the following HTML document:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('''<value uri=" /user/var/120/10251/0/0/12242" strValue="61" unit="°C" decPlaces="0" scaleFactor="10" advTextOffset="0">605</value>''')

>>> soup.value
<value advtextoffset="0" decplaces="0" scalefactor="10" strvalue="61" unit="°C" uri=" /user/var/120/10251/0/0/12242">605</value>
```

you can access the attributes in two ways:

- By key, similar to a dictionary:

  ```
  strvalue = soup.value['strvalue']
  ```
- Or through the `attrs` dictionary:

  ```
  strvalue = soup.value.attrs['strvalue']
  ```

Note that you need to use the lower case version of the attribute name, i.e. `strvalue`, not `strValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<value uri=" /user/var/120/10251/0/0/12242" strValue="61" unit="°C" decPlaces="0" scaleFactor="10" advTextOffset="0">605</value>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
strValue = soup.select_one('value').get('strvalue')
```

Answer (score -1):

i solved the problem. i did it like this:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'http://192.168.7.5:8080/user/var/120/10251/0/0/12242'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
page_soup_value = page_soup.value
page_soup_value.get('strvalue')
```